# как преобразовать строку, чтобы буквы шли в обратном порядке в языке R

Tags: r

как преобразовать строку, чтобы буквы шли в обратном порядке в языке R

Answer (score 3):

```
rev(strsplit("abc", split = "")[[1]])
[1] "c" "b" "a"
paste0(rev(strsplit("abc", split = "")[[1]]), collapse = "")
[1] "cba"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   #Вариант 1: Используем пакет stringi
   s <- "abc"
   library(stringi)
   stri_reverse(s)
```

> [1] "cba"

```
   #Вариант 2: Используем substr, for, nchar
   #вырезаем по одному символу с хвоста и склеиваем
   s <- "abc"
   tmp.s = ""

   for (i in nchar(s):1) tmp.s <- paste0(tmp.s, substr(s, i, i))
   tmp.s
```

> [1] "cba"

```
   #Вариант 3:Используем возможность замены символов прямо в строке
   #substr(x, start, stop) <- 
   s <- "abc"
   tmp.s <-s
   for (i in nchar(s):1) substr(tmp.s, nchar(s)-i+1,nchar(s)-i+1) <- substr(s, i, i)
   tmp.s
```

> [1] "cba"